# How can you access any android classes using JNI in Qt?

Tags: qt, java-native-interface

I'm a newbie on Qt and JNI so please edit or correct me if anything I am saying is off.

How can you access the classes in Android in the C++ code in Qt Creator? It is seemingly not possible to access classes not directly supported by QtAndroidExtras import .

e.g. TextView, BlueToothReceiver, and the countless many useful classes

Comment: Have you tried using [`QAndroidJniObject`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qandroidjniobject.html)?

Comment: Currently working on it. In the documentation I was confused, so I didn't know you could use it in this way, which I think I can now. It is still rather difficult even with finding the correct documents. I will continue working on it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good example:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtandroidextras-notification-example.html

It is possible to call any class from C++ per jni.

Comment: I used this example, it helps!