# Qt QAndroidJniObject list all extras of android.content.Intent object

Tags: android, qt

Is there a way to list all extras of a QAndroidJniObject? I can't find anything on the c++ side, only java.
I would like to create a QMap<QString, QVariant> with all the extras.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "extras"?

Comment: A `QAndroidJniObject` is a wrapper around any kind of Java object. Are you talking one that specifically wraps an Android `Intent` object?

Comment: @Michael yeah sorry I forgot to mention that my QAndroidJniObject is the representation of an Android Intent

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37548559/how-can-you-access-any-android-classes-using-jni-in-qt